# Multivariate linear regression with missing points without imputation

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-imputation

I am currently trying to perform a vanilla multivariate linear regression-
imagine the equations are
$y_1 = a_0x_{0,1} + a_1x_{1,1}... a_nx_{n-1,1}$

$y_2 = a_0x_{0,2} + a_1x_{1,2}... a_nx_{n-1,2}$

...

$y_p = a_0x_{0,p} + a_1x_{1,p}... a_nx_{n-1,p}$

The catch is some of my $x_{i,j}$ are missing. I am currently imputing missing values, but want to avoid adding 'incorrect' data. Is there a way I can perform the regression with the values missing and get accurate results.

Note: both n and p are > 1 million so I have a lot of samples with <10% missing data.

Comment: The regression won't work without assumptions about the missing values, and these assumptions would translate to imputations anyhow...

Comment: 1. Suppose $n=1$, then $y_1=?$. 2. error terms are needed.